# my filter function (filterFn) isnt working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

my filter function (filterFn) isnt working and showinf  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')` in console  but if i console out `el.DepartmentId` it shows the id as 1

you can also download it to try it yourself here is the url:

https://github.com/naveednaseer/delete_later/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Department.js

here is the code:

```
const Department = () => {


    let [department, setDepartment] = useState([])
    let [values, setValues] = useState({
        modalTitle: '',
        departmentName: '',
        departmentId: 0,

        departmentIdFilter: "",
        departmentNameFilter: "",
        departmentsWithoutFilter: [],
    })

    useEffect (() => {
        getDepartments()
    }, [])


    let filterFn = () =>{
        let departmentIdFilter = values.departmentIdFilter
        let departmentNameFilter = values.departmentNameFilter

        values.departmentsWithoutFilter = [...department]
        console.log(values.departmentsWithoutFilter)

        let filteredData = values.departmentsWithoutFilter.filter(
            function(el){
                console.log(el)
                console.log(el.DepartmentId)
                return el.DepartmentId.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    departmentIdFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                ) &&
                el.departmentName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    departmentNameFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                )

            }
        )
        console.log(values.departmentsWithoutFilter)
        setDepartment(filteredData)

    }


    let changeDepartmentIdFilter = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, 'departmentIdFilter': e.target.value})
        filterFn()
    }
    
    
    let changeDepartmentNameFilter = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, 'departmentNameFilter': e.target.value})
        console.log(values)
        filterFn()
    }


    let getDepartments = async () => {
        let response = await fetch (variables.API_URL + "department")
        let data = await response.json()

        setDepartment(data)
    }


    let changeDepartmentName = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, 'departmentName': e.target.value})
    }

    let addClick = () => {
        setValues({...values,modalTitle:"Add Department", departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
    }

    let editClick = (dep) => {
        setValues({...values,modalTitle:"Edit Department", departmentName: dep.DepartmentName, departmentId: dep.DepartmentId})
        console.log('default values', values)
        console.log(dep.DepartmentId)
    }

    let createClick = () => {
        fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                DepartmentName: values.departmentName
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            getDepartments()
            console.log(result)
            setValues({...values, departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }


    let updateClick = () => {
        fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/", {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                DepartmentId: values.departmentId,
                DepartmentName: values.departmentName
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            getDepartments()
            console.log(result)
            setValues({...values, departmentName: "", departmentId: "0"})
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }


    let deleteClick = (id) => {
        if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")){
            fetch(variables.API_URL+"department/"+id, {
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            })


            .then(() => {
                getDepartments()
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
    }


    return (
        <div>

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => addClick()}>Add Department</button>

            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentIdFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                            DepartmentId
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input className="form-control m-2" onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentNameFilter(e)}} placeholder='Filter' />
                            DepartmentName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Options
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {department.map((dep) => 

                        <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                            <td>
                                
                                {/* >>>>>>EDIT BUTTON<<<<<< */}
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => editClick(dep)}>
                                    
                                </button>

                                {/* >>>>>>>DELETE BUTTON<<<<<<<<<<< */}
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1" onClick={() => deleteClick(dep.DepartmentId)}>
                                   
                                </button>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title">{values.modalTitle}</h5>

                            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            </button>

                        </div>

                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <span className="input-group-text">Department Name</span>
                                <input name = 'departmentName' type="text" className="form-control" value={values.departmentName} onChange={(e) => {changeDepartmentName(e)}} />
                                {/* <input type="text" className="form-control" value={departmentName} onChange={changeDepartmentName} /> */}
                            </div>

                            {values.departmentId == 0 ?
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => createClick()}>Create</button> :
                                null
                            }

                            {values.departmentId != 0 ?
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start" onClick={() => updateClick()}>Edit</button> :
                                null
                            }

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Department
```

Any help would be appriciated as i have been stuck for hours now (sorry for messy code)

Comment: Are you sure it is DepartmentId? you have a lot of toString() calls `console.log(el.DepartmentId, departmentIdFilter, el.departmentName, departmentNameFilter);`

Comment: Use conditional rendering with Optional chaining (?.)

Comment: departmentIdFilter and departmentNameFilter are lagging for example if i write acc it consoles ac what i mean is it is one step back from what i am writing

Comment: @rezaghorbani conditional rendering for what????

Comment: @epascarello pretty sure it is DepartmentId when i console out el there are only two options el.DepartmentId and el.DepartmentName

Comment: Sorry I mean use Optional chain to don't get these errors, also you can use useCallback for the function and the value state as a dependency of  hook to track the value state changes when you are using setValue. Because somtimes calling filterFn and setValues may be at the same time.

Comment: @epascarello oh wow found the problem in the line `el.departmentName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(`  it was supposed to be el.DepartmentName   but it is still acting weird it  dosent filter if i write a number in id filter but then if i write anything after that it filters for previous number i hope you can help